# combined contents of 2 columns can't contain duplicates

Tags: mysql, constraint, mysql-8.0

This is a hard question to ask. I find it difficult to put into words.

I have two columns where the content of column A can not appear in column B and vice versa. So, the combined contents of both columns needs to be unique.

In other words: I want any value that already exists in column A not to be allowed in *either* A or B. Likewise for B (no duplicates in B *or* A).

Is there a way to do this in MySQL with only a table schema change?

I also don't want to use triggers to prevent insertions.

MySQL version 8.0.18

Comment: How can you solve this with a separate table and foreign keys?

Comment: @Lennart i tried my solution with a separate table and it did not work, i ran into the same problem. Ultimately i went with a trigger and constraint check solution. Not happy about it, but it is working.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that I can think of to do this (without using triggers) is to use [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/). Doesn't really answer the question (MySQL), but is interesting functionality to explore - see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=a45671e00eb4b29ab98e3778dd743ba9)!

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  column_A INTEGER NOT NULL,
  column_B INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT a_uq UNIQUE (column_A),
  CONSTRAINT b_uq UNIQUE (column_B),
  CONSTRAINT a_ne_b_ck CHECK (column_A != column_B),
  CONSTRAINT a_ni_b_ck CHECK (column_A NOT IN (SELECT column_B FROM test)),
  CONSTRAINT b_ni_a_ck CHECK (column_B NOT IN (SELECT column_A FROM test))
);
```

It does make the table declaration more complex (*con*) but with the massive *pro* of not having to maintain triggers oneself. It would appear from the error messages that Firebird uses triggers in the background - better that the server maintain them than me!

```
--
-- The next two INSERTs work (as one would expect)
--
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 5);
```

Then, to test (standard functionality first):

```
--
-- This doesn't work - breaches UNIQUE constraint on column_A
-- Look at the quality of the error message!
--
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 7);  -- 2 is a dup in column_A
```

fails with the error:

```
violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "A_UQ" on 
table "TEST" Problematic key value is ("COLUMN_A" = 2)
```

Look at the quality of that error message - even telling you the offending value!

Then we try (again standard `CHECK` constraint stuff):

```
--
-- This doesn't work - breaches the column_A != column_B CHECK. Easy, peasy!
-- All RDBMS do this - even MySQL now since version 8!
--
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 4);
```

Error message:

```
Operation violates CHECK constraint A_NE_B_CK on view or 
table TEST At trigger 'CHECK_1'
```

Now, we test the SQL **within the `CHECK` constraint**!

```
--
-- This is where it gets interesting! Notice that it **_won't_** allow a value
-- that's in column_B be inserted into column_A! Pretty cool!
--
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5, 9);
```

gives the error:

```
Operation violates CHECK constraint A_NI_B_CK on view or table 
TEST At trigger 'CHECK_3'
```

The SQL in the `CHECK` constraint works the other way round also - see the fiddle. Note the part of the error message where it says: `table TEST At trigger 'CHECK_3'` - triggers at work in the background!

This is **really powerful** stuff! It's such a shame that Firebird isn't more popular/widespread - it really deserves the no. 2 spot in [F/LOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) database ecosphere!

Incredibly, MySQL only recently introduced `CHECK` constraints (only at least 25 years after all its other major - and not so major - competitors). But, now it appears to be making serious efforts to catch up! But nobody else (AFAIK) has SQL in `CHECK` constraints, not even the mighty Oracle, MS SQL Server or PostgreSQL (note to self - suggest this on the lists!).

Comment: I found this comparison chart (includes CHECK constraints with sub-query ) whilst looking for something else:  https://www.sql-workbench.eu/dbms_comparison.html . It appears that H2 (imight not be concidered a real DBMS) also supports this.

Comment: @Lennart - the only thing I would say about H2 is that there are an awful lot of red "No"s in the H2 column - <teacher writing H2's grade - "interesting, but could do better!">