# Simplifying Function with Recursive CTE and/or Window Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, window-functions, recursive

I'm trying to come up with a Recursive CTE and/or Window Function to create a function.

After days, I've boiled the function down to (pseudocode) 
where I have `N` and `B`, and need to generate `E`:

> **E**<sub>n</sub> = **B**<sub>n</sub> * (1 - SUM(**E**<sub>1</sub>, **E**<sub>2</sub>, ... **E**<sub>n-1</sub>))

#### Examples:

```
╔═══╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ N ║ B           ║ E           ║
╠═══╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 0 ║ 0.142857143 ║ 0.142857143 ║
║ 1 ║ 0.285714286 ║ 0.244897959 ║
║ 2 ║ 0.285714286 ║ 0.174927114 ║
║ 3 ║ 0.285714286 ║ 0.124947938 ║
║ 4 ║ 0.285714286 ║ 0.089248527 ║
║ 5 ║ 0.4         ║ 0.089248527 ║
║ 6 ║ 0.666666667 ║ 0.089248527 ║
║ 7 ║ 1           ║ 0.044624264 ║
╚═══╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

> E<sub>0</sub> = 0.143 * (1 - 0) = 0.143
>   E<sub>1</sub> = 0.286 * (1 - 0.143) = 0.245
>   E<sub>2</sub> = 0.286 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245)) = 0.175
>   E<sub>3</sub> = 0.286 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245 + 0.175)) = 0.125
>   E<sub>4</sub> = 0.286 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245 + 0.175 + 0.125)) = 0.089
>   E<sub>5</sub> = 0.400 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245 + 0.175 + 0.125 + 0.089)) = 0.089
>   E<sub>6</sub> = 0.667 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245 + 0.175 + 0.125 + 0.089 + 0.089)) = 0.089
>   E<sub>7</sub> = 1.000 * (1 - (0.143 + 0.245 + 0.175 + 0.125 + 0.089 + 0.089 + 0.089)) = 0.044

If the table above was in Excel, `C2 = B2 * (1 - 0)` (base) and `C3 = B3 * (1 - SUM(C$2:C2))` (recursive)

### What I've tried:

#### Windowed Functions

Tried `SUM(...) OVER(ORDER BY [N] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`, but can't reference the column recursively.

#### Recursive CTE

Tried several iterations of:

```sql
WITH B AS ([Num], [Best], [Effective Rate]) AS (
    SELECT *
        , [Best]
    FROM A
    WHERE [Num] = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.*
        , (1 - [Effective Rate]) * A.[Best]
    FROM B
    JOIN A ON A.[Num] = B.[Num] + 1 
)
```

and some with an extra column in the CTE, but it only covers 1 previous row and results after 2nd row are wrong.

#### Recursive CTE with Windowed Function

From all that I've tried, it seems that the recursive segment of the CTE is calculated independently of the other results, and `SUM(...) OVER(...)` only works on the current row. (With regard to the above table, all values of `E` would be `0.142857143`).

I assume this is because the `UNION ALL` happens all at once, and not incrementally.

### Alternative Solutions

What I would ***really*** like to happen is to simplify the above equation, and/or transform it into an iterative function.

**Bonus:** If anyone cares to know the source of this information, it's used to calculate [MACRS depreciation](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p946#en_US_2019_publink1000107747) for tax purposes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need an extra column to carry along the running total ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90675b51f9b61293b514d6ebb0e479fa)).

In the recursive part of the CTE below `R` refers to the "previous" row and `A` the current one so referencing the column from `R` is your `SUM(E1, E2, ... En-1)`.

```
WITH R
     AS (SELECT N,
                B,
                E = B,
                RunningTotalE = B
         FROM   A
         WHERE  N = 0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT A.N,
                A.B,
                E = A.B * ( 1 - R.RunningTotalE ),
                RunningTotalE = A.B * ( 1 - R.RunningTotalE ) + R.RunningTotalE
         FROM   R
                JOIN A
                  ON A.N = R.N + 1)
SELECT N,
       B,
       E = CAST(E AS DECIMAL(10,9))
FROM   R
```

Comment: I couldnt understand what runningtotal is doing here..could there be a more of simplified explanation