# Creating a table with CHECK constraints in MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

I created a table `ORDER` using Mysql Workbench as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rr`.`ORDER` (
  `Order No.` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The order of the inspected equipment',
  `Order_Type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'External or Internal work',
  `Engine_Description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description of the Engine',
  `Equipment_Quantity` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT ' Number of the inspected equipment',
  `Required_Task` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Whether Repair or Overhaul',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order No.`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '\n';
```

So I need to know how to make a constraint where if the value of the `Order_Type` field is 'External' then the value of  automatically the value of `Engine_Description`  will be `NULL` or else a value will be added?

Also, if I want to do the same for two different entities?

Comment: first please don't use reserved words for Table,/column names, in the long run this amkes iftn problems. CHECK constraints are only implmeneted in mysql 8, so you have to use trigger for that purpose

Comment: Engine_description does not accept NULL values though because you have it defined as NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment, use Triggers for that purpose

Like shown here, you have add every constraint as if clause to your trigger., because mysql 5.x doesn't support `CHECK` constraints

Also note that `Order` is a **reserved word**, and you shouldn't use them in table or column names else you have always to use Backticks in every Query

Your field `Engine_Description` is declared as **NOT NULL** so it can't be set to NULL i set it so to an empty descrition

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ORDER` (
>   `Order No.` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The order of the inspected equipment',
>   `Order_Type` CHAR(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'External or Internal work',
>   `Engine_Description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Description of the Engine',
>   `Equipment_Quantity` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT ' Number of the inspected equipment',
>   `Required_Task` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Whether Repair or Overhaul',
>   PRIMARY KEY (`Order No.`))
> ENGINE = InnoDB
> COMMENT = '\n';
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_orders_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON `ORDER` FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>  IF NEW.Order_Type  ='External' THEN
>      SET new.`Engine_Description` = '';
>  END IF;
>
> END;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_orders_UPDATE
> BEFORE UPDATE
> ON `ORDER` FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>  IF NEW.Order_Type  ='External' THEN
>      SET new.`Engine_Description` = '';
>  END IF;
>
> EN
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `ORDER` VALUES (1,'External','test descrition',1,'Repair')
> ,(2,'Internal','test descrition',2,'Repair')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `ORDER`
> ```
>
> ```
> Order No. | Order_Type | Engine_Description | Equipment_Quantity | Required_Task
> --------: | :--------- | :----------------- | -----------------: | :------------
>         1 | External   |                    |                  1 | Repair       
>         2 | Internal   | test descrition    |                  2 | Repair
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6572a0d3a409a2c90a7313557785b235)*

Comment: There's a small error in your `TRIGGER` - you set `Engine_Description` to `NOT NULL` and also, `ON INSERT` and `ON DELETE` you have set it to `''`- i.e. the empty string which is **NOT** `NULL` - I've corrected your fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f0fb8f48636aab121c4aceeed29c9962) if you'd care to integrate it into your answer?

Comment: @Vérace i set nothing the field is declared as NOT NULL **by the user**, so i set it correctly, as he doesn't want any descrition in it, i will add that to my answer.

Comment: The OP said `if the value of the Order_Type field is 'External' then the value of automatically the value of Engine_Description will be NULL` - and not `''` (empty string) - my modification of your fiddle answers the question as asked - obviously removing the `NOT NULL` from `Engine_Description` is required to answer the question **as asked** - but your explanation of what you did is a reasonable alternative - plus you answered the question for the versions requested by the OP - so +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very elegantly using `CHECK` constraints in [MySQL >=  8.0.16](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/) as follows (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fae4cdd0975ac005902f04ef97872c62)):

Your table (changed slightly)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders 
(
  order_no INT,
  order_type CHAR(8) CHECK (order_type IN ('e', 'i')) ,
  engine_description VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'The default',  -- NOT NULL constraint removed
  CONSTRAINT ot_ed_ck 
    CHECK ((order_type = 'i') OR (order_type = 'e' AND engine_description IS NULL))
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO orders 
VALUES 
(1, 'i', 'safadf'), (2, 'i', 'xcvzxv'), (3, 'e', NULL);
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

Result:

```
order_no    order_type  engine_description
       1             i              safadf
       2             i              xcvzxv
       3             e                null
```

So far, so good.

Then we try to do this:

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('4', 'e', 'xxxxx');
```

and we get the error message:

```
Check constraint 'ot_ed_ck' is violated.
```

Which is exactly what we want!

To cover the case of `or else a value will be added?` in the question, by which I presume you mean a `DEFAULT` - if we specifically exclude `engine_description` from the list of values to be `INSERT`ed as follows:

```
INSERT INTO orders (order_no, order_type) VALUES (5, 'i');
```

and we `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
```

We obtain:

```
order_no    order_type  engine_description
      1              i              safadf
      2              i              xcvzxv
      3              e                null  
      5              i         The default   <<----- Default!
```

I would **strongly urge** you to upgrade to MySQL 8 - it's now at version 8.0.22, so any major version change wrinkles will have been ironed out by now - you get all sorts of goodies - like `CHECK` constraints that I just outlined, [`COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION`](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/)s (available from 8.0.1, aka the `WITH` clause) and also `GENERATED` columns ([5.7.5](https://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/)).

If you cannot upgrade to version 8, then you'll have to use `TRIGGER`s (as per [@nbk's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/280957/34007)), but you asked for constraints so that's what I supplied.

Also, what exactly do you mean by:

> Also, if I want to do the same for two different entities?

If you mean constraints between two fields in the same table (`intra`-table), you have the example above, if you mean between two tables (`inter`-table), then on any server ([bar Firebird](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/260867/34007)), you'll have to use `TRIGGER`s!

Finally, a word of advice - do **NOT** use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) as table or column names (in this case `Order`)- it's confusing, makes debugging more difficult and is not good practice.  Normally, I use singular table names, but I make an exception (obviously) for `ORDER`s - a table is a set and should be singular (IMHO).

p.s. welcome to the forum!